# How could I pass the float number by value in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

In the following code, I passed the "1.3f" to printFloat, but it was the wrong value (in this case, -2.000000) after was "f" received. And there is a warning that "AppDelegate may not respond to -printFloat:"

Where did I get it wrong?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self printFloat:1.3f];
}

- (void)printFloat:(float)f {
    NSLog(@"%f",f);
}
```

Comment: Is `printFloat:` declared in the interface? Otherwise, I'd guess, it's due to float/double promotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily resolve both your problems by adding the method prototype into the header file (`<sameName>.h`):

```
- (void)printFloat:(float)f;
```

Comment: Thanks!
My advertence, sorry for asking a low question.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the correct definition in the class' header file, and you still cannot pass floats by reference, make sure you're not overriding an existing method of a parent class...

For example, I had this problem because my class was derived from `NSMutableData` (which I did not know then), and I added a method,

```c
 - (void) initWithLength:(float)length;
```

to my class. `NSMutableData` already defines this method, and it uses an integer.

My method then produced garbage: the float value was passed as 0x0 no matter what I sent it...